# Slow HEIC Viewing on Mac

Tags: catalina, quicklook, heic

When viewing HEIC images with QuickLook from Finder on my MacBook Pro (2019) there is always a slight delay of almost a second. Other formats (jpg/png) work just fine.

When viewing the images in Photos they show up instantly.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Note: Technically HEIC does require more processing power to decode and encode, as it uses HEVC codec, than JPEG or PNG. But yeah, `Finder` on macOS is overall slow.

Comment: It seems like a rather strange design choice by Apple. Going through a bunch of jpg files is a breeze, and only larger jpg files cause a big of "lag" where the old jpg file will stay on screen for a moment before the new one is loaded. For HEIC files, it definitely takes longer than it needs to to load, and the "loading" screen is shown every time a new image is previewed, causing your screen to "flash" every time you change an image. I'm not even sure if this might be a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found no fix I wrote a [small app](https://github.com/laktak/termplug) that uses macOS components to display the HEIC instantly.

Comment: It would be nice if someone could write a *QuickLook* plug for this. I'm a little disappointed at how slowly QuickLook loads HEIC files, whereas third-party apps (like ApolloOne) loads them in just a fraction of a second

Comment: I'm still on macOS High Sierra so I cannot compile the program (Swift is too old). Can you compile and release the program?

Comment: @JoyJin I don't have a dev cert but give this  a try: https://github.com/laktak/termplug/releases/tag/v1.0

Comment: @laktak Unfortunately, the app is built for macOS 10.15 and higher, so I can't run it (it won't open even when I changed the minimal system version to 10.13 in `Info.plist`). Also, it unzips to `Contents` so I'm guessing that zip did not include the app directory but instead the Contents directory.

Comment: @laktak I guess the version of Swift and other libraries you are using are too new for macOS 10.13, so it doesn't really matter. I will try it in a VM when I have time. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using a third-party app such as [ApolloOne](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apolloone-photo-video-viewer/id1044484672?mt=12). I have tried and succeeded in skimming through 50 HEIC files in just a couple of seconds. In contrast, QuickLook took nearly a whole second to view each individual HEIC file.